# How to find repeateds in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to find repeated characters in a list, but they should be side-to-side.

For example:

```
lst = ["A", "B", "B", "A"]
```

I want to detect the `"B"`s but not the `"A"`s. If there is no repeated characters side-by-side, my program will print a message and finish the game. How can I make that happen?

EDIT: Thanks for all the comments, they were all true. I just needed to find if "-X-" is duplicated and I did it with converting the list to a string. Again, thank you all!

Comment: I downvoted because you can find the answer with like a minute of Google searching.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get some help here, you'll need to try to solve the problem yourself first, and post your attempt with an explanation of what part of it is not working.

Comment: @dfundako I am not always asking for help in this platform, but thanks for giving a hand to a beginner

Comment: @SteveArcher I couldn't find something in my head. I can do it without the sideways condition but not with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby 

def any_side_by_side(iterable): 
     for k, group in groupby(iterable): 
         next(group) # discard first group element
         try: 
             next(group) # is there a second element?
             return True 
         except StopIteration: 
             pass 
     return False
```

A shorter but less memory efficient way would be

```
any(len(list(group)) > 1 for k, group in groupby(iterable))
```

Demo:

```
>>> any_side_by_side(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A'])                                                                             
True
>>> any_side_by_side(['B', 'A', 'B', 'A'])                                                                             
False
```

The function above will return `True` if there is any sequence of repeated elements in your list, `False` otherwise.

Another option is the `pairwise` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the `itertools` docs. You can copy-paste it or import it from [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/).

```
>>> from more_itertools import pairwise                                                                                
>>>                                                                                                                    
>>> any(x == y for x,y in pairwise(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']))                                                              
True
>>> any(x == y for x,y in pairwise(['B', 'A', 'B', 'A']))                                                              
False
```

Both of these solutions will work for any iterable, not just lists. They also don't create intermediary lists in memory which are not needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to know if two elements side-by-side are equals, this will do:

```
def any_side_by_side(l):
    return any(first == second for first, second in zip(l, l[1:]))


print(any_side_by_side(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']))
print(any_side_by_side(['B', 'A', 'B', 'A']))
```

**Output**

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy` you can compare the list elements to the next element for each list item.

```
import numpy as np

any(np.where(np.asarray(lst[1:]) == np.asarray(lst[:-1])))
```

`lst[1:]` represents the next item in the list.  In your example `lst[1:]` would be `["B", "B", "A"]`.  Since the last item doesn't have a neighbor `lst[:-1]` gets all elements except the last one, which would be `["A", "B", "B"]`.  The code above compares those two arrays looking for matches.  If any match is found the code will evaluate `True` indicating there is at least one pair of repeat values, otherwise it will evaluate `False`.

Comment: I believe you need to adjust a bit this code in order to get the proper answer. I believe `any(np.where(np.asarray(lst[1:]) == np.asarray(lst[:-1])))` would do.

Comment: Right, yes, sorry, OP used a list and for this to work the list would need to be converted to numpy arrays.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can loop and check if the last value would be same as current value or not

```
lst = ["A", "B", "B", "A"]
tmp = ""
dup = ""
for x in lst:
    if x == tmp:
        print("Side by side value detected" + x)
    else:
        for s in dup.split(","):
            if s == x:
                print("Duplicate but not side by side "+ x)
        dup = dup + "," + x
    tmp = x
```

You can write else case if you want to print not similar side by side values
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package can be very useful to resolve this in an easy way.

You first define a `Series` from your list and then create a shift and compare to the original. You can finally get the result if you get any subsequent duplicate or not and even get duplicate strings.

```
import pandas as pd
lst = ["A", "B", "B", "A"]
df = pd.Series(lst)
check = df.eq(df.shift())
```

Then you can get the boolean stating if you have subsequent duplicates or not with:

```
>> check.any()
True
```

And you can even get which values are subsequent duplicates this way:

```
>> df[check]
2    B
```